# Exponentiation in ECC

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption

I have a naive question, what is the nomenclature of exponentiation mean in ECC?

I was reading about exponential ElGamal, what does it mean if a generator point $G^x$ ?  What does $G * \ldots * G$ actually mean?

I know what point double and point addition are, they are inline with scalar operations with the base point.  How can two curve points be multiplied together?

Comment: They don't. The authors simply have decided to take the points of an elliptic curve to be a multiplicative instead of an additive group. This is a different way of writing what is more commonly known as scalar multiplication.

Comment: hmm, this is a bit confusing, so in ECDH what does  Y =xG  represent?

Comment: It probably means the same thing. Which source are you reading? What does its notation/definitions section say?

Comment: I was reading the basic scheme here: http://knot.kaist.ac.kr/seminar/archive/46/46.pdf

Comment: The "exponentation" is just a repeated addition of the base point $g$, normally written $[n]g$ for $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, negative $n$ use the inverse of the corresponding positive $n$..

Comment: Based on the paper I was reading, I believe Exponentiation represented scalar multiplication and point multiplication represented point addition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a group, where there is by definition only one operation, *exponentiation* means repeated application of the group operation, whatever that is. That is, if the group operation is noted $\circ$, $g$ is a group element, and $x$ is a positive integer, $g^x$ is short for $\underbrace{g\circ g\circ\dots\circ g}_\text{$x$ terms}$.

In elliptic curve groups, the operation is the point addition with which you are hopefully familiar.